# Get first column text from table on onclick function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying this, but can't make it happen. I am trying to get the first column text. First column text contains the room Number.

Here is what I have done so far:

```
$.each(eval(data), function(index, item) {
                $('#data-Tables tbody').append('<tr><td>' + item.ROOM + '</td><td>' + item.GUEST_NAME + '</td><td><a onclick="showDetails(e)" class="actionBtn">Details</a></td></tr>');
            });
```

I used `onclick="showDetails(e)"` on `a` tag, then I defined function on page:

```
function showDetails(e){
    $(this).text('changebtn text');
}
```

I get this error on Firebug:

```
ReferenceError: e is not defined
```

I also tried without `e`, I didn't get the error message on Firebug.

But in both cases the `$(this)` didn't work. How can I get the first column data?

I can't use `selector.click` because it's not working. I even tried with `document.ready` and made many attempts, it's some kind of problem with gadget.

Is there any way to get the first column data on dynamic table when clicked on button?

Here is the screenshot of my gadget:

[image]

Comment: try reading documentation for `onclick` and use it properly. Simpler to use a jQuery click handler

Comment: Check here http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onclick.asp

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When using `onclick` in HTML you will not receive a parameter called `event` or `e`. So if you remove `e` from both places you wont get the error.

To find `this` in your function you could use the following to send the object as a parameter.

**HTML**

```
onclick="showDetails(this)"
```

**JS**

```
function showDetails(obj){
   $(obj).text('changebtn text');
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you are trying to do?

```
$.each(eval(data), function(index, item) {
       var tr$ = $('<tr><td>' + item.ROOM + '</td><td>' + item.GUEST_NAME + '</td><td><a onclick="showDetails(e)" class="actionBtn">Details</a></td></tr>');
       tr$.on("click",function(){
          window.alert($(this).find("td:first").text());  
       });
       $('#data-Tables tbody').append(tr$);
 });
```

This should fire an alert displaying the text of the first column when you click on a row.

Comment: Thanks, i will try this too. but problem fixed with Afsa answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
$.each(eval(data), function(index, item) {
$('#data-Tables tbody').append('<tr><td>' + item.ROOM + '</td><td>' + item.GUEST_NAME + '</td><td><a class="actionBtn">Details</a></td></tr>');
});


$(#data-Tables td).eq(2).on('click',function(e){
e.preventDefault();
$(this).text('changebtn text');
});
```

Don't tight couple JS with HTML, make it separate for better maintenence.